# Import Process in Magento 2.4.6 Interfering with Each Other (Magento 2.4.6 )

Tags: importexport, magento2.4.6

When two import processes are initiated simultaneously in Magento 2.4.6, a severe bug arises. In my case, during the customer composite import and product import occurring concurrently, an error occurs within the customer import process. Upon further investigation and debugging, it becomes apparent that Magento erroneously incorporates product data into the customer import procedure.

For more details:- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37593

-In Magento 2.4.6, a critical bug arises in the import process due to the default batch size limit defined in the configuration file "vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/config.xml". By default, the batch size is set to 100. Consequently, when importing data, Magento inserts records into the "importexport_importdata" table based on this batch size. For instance, if there are 1400 records, Magento will insert 14 rows into the table during the import validation phase.

Upon clicking the import button, Magento retrieves the data from the aforementioned table and proceeds with the import process. However, an issue occurs when any import contains more than 100 records, leading to the creation of multiple entries in the table. This becomes problematic when two import processes simultaneously validate their files, as each process adds its validated data to the "importexport_importdata" table. This interference causes issues during the subsequent import steps.

[image]

Steps:-

1. Log in to Magento 2.4.6 admin in two separate system.
2. In both systems, navigate to "System" > "Data Transfer" > "Import".
3. In the first system, select "Customers and Addresses" (single file) with billing and shipping address data, ensuring there are more than 500 records.
4. In the second system, select "Catalog Product Import" with 50 to 60 records.
5. Validate both selected imports.
6. In the first system, click on the "Import" button.
7. Within the next second, click on the "Import" button in the second system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is default Magento bug and they are working on it, I have found temporarily solution for it,

Increase the batch size of the default import to avoid interfering with each other.

Default batch size is 100.

[image]

Increase that to 5000 or more according to your Data.

[image]

Make sure you have overridden that in the custom module.

You might have old records due to old errors, truncate the table **importexport_importdata** and try to import again.